# Dynamically includes with query

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have a footer included in my base template with:

```
{% include "footer.html %}
```

I need to show it in every page. But the footer has several statics which needs to be calculated with several queries each time the page loads.
As far as I know, this include cannot run queries because any views is called. And I don't want to replicate the query for that in all my views, I think it's a dirty solution.
What's the best practice in this case? I think it's a quite common problem.

Answer (score 2):

Although context processors are good for including standard things in every template, I suspect for your purposes a [custom template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/custom-template-tags/) that renders the entire footer would be a better bet - probably an inclusion tag would do the job.

Answer (score 1):

If statistics are global (not something related to specific page/request) you can implement your custom context processor which can calculate statistics and add corresponding variables in the context. That context variables/dict can be used by `footer.html` to put the statistics.

Refer [Writing custom context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors)

Comment: uhm, but they are not available in render_to_response

Answer (score 0):

You can use [context processors](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter09/#cn21) to run your queries in all views and update your context with necessary data.

Answer (score 0):

What about creating a Context Processor, and return the query from there ?
The result will be available in every view, if that's what you desire ?

Answer (score 0):

You should write context processor to work this out :

[writing context processors](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors)

Answer (score 0):

Another option not mentioned here so far are [custom template tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/custom-template-tags/). Depending on what exactly you want to do a context processor might be overkill.